# Pass image from SimpleDraweeView in RecyclerView.Adapter to a new activity in android

Tags: android

I'm using RecyclerView.Adapter to display images in Activity1. I want to add button functionality to each image to display that same image in another activity (Activity2). Each image is webp and is displayed in Activity1 in a SimpleDraweeView.
I added the setOnClickListener in onCreateViewHolder so now the Views act like a button, but how do I read and pass the right image to Activity2 with each click? 
(This is basic code from example WhatsApp sticker app, which I am trying to modify).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class StickerPreviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StickerPreviewViewHolder> {

    @NonNull
    private StickerPack stickerPack;

    private final int cellSize;
    private int cellLimit;
    private int cellPadding;
    private final int errorResource;


    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    public Context context;
    public String packageName;
    public String stickerName;

    StickerPreviewAdapter(
            @NonNull final LayoutInflater layoutInflater,
            final int errorResource,
            final int cellSize,
            final int cellPadding,
            @NonNull final StickerPack stickerPack) {
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.cellPadding = cellPadding;
        this.cellLimit = 0;
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
        this.errorResource = errorResource;
        this.stickerPack = stickerPack;
        this.mContext = StickerApplication.getContext();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StickerPreviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
        View itemView=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sticker_image, viewGroup, false);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(v ->{
        });

        StickerPreviewViewHolder vh = new StickerPreviewViewHolder(itemView);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = vh.stickerPreviewView.getLayoutParams(); 
                 //stickerPreviewView is SimpleDraweeView
        layoutParams.height = cellSize;
        layoutParams.width = cellSize;
        vh.stickerPreviewView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        vh.stickerPreviewView.setPadding(cellPadding, cellPadding, cellPadding, cellPadding);
        return vh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StickerPreviewViewHolder stickerPreviewViewHolder, final int i) {
        stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView.setImageResource(errorResource);
        packageName = stickerPack.identifier;
        stickerName = stickerPack.getStickers().get(i).imageFileName;
        stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView.setImageURI(StickerPackLoader.getStickerAssetUri(packageName, stickerName));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int numberOfPreviewImagesInPack;
        numberOfPreviewImagesInPack = stickerPack.getStickers().size();
        if (cellLimit > 0) {
            return Math.min(numberOfPreviewImagesInPack, cellLimit);
        }
        return numberOfPreviewImagesInPack;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java
What you want to do is pass the stickername to the next `Activity` inside an `Intent` and then in the next `Activity` you want to read out the stickername again and use it there. I'd recommend you to follow some of these basic training sessions to understand how the system works.
Oh, and set the `OnClickListener` inside `onBindViewHolder` instead of `onCreateViewHolder` - that way you have access to the data at the right place.

Comment: Moving everything to onBindViewHolder as the missing bit! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The working code:
(Thanks to Darwind's help)

Activity 1:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class StickerPreviewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StickerPreviewViewHolder> {

    @NonNull
    private StickerPack stickerPack;

    private final int cellSize;
    private int cellLimit;
    private int cellPadding;
    private final int errorResource;


    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    public Context context;

    StickerPreviewAdapter(
            @NonNull final LayoutInflater layoutInflater,
            final int errorResource,
            final int cellSize,
            final int cellPadding,
            @NonNull final StickerPack stickerPack) {
        this.cellSize = cellSize;
        this.cellPadding = cellPadding;
        this.cellLimit = 0;
        this.layoutInflater = layoutInflater;
        this.errorResource = errorResource;
        this.stickerPack = stickerPack;
        this.mContext = StickerApplication.getContext();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StickerPreviewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
        View itemView=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sticker_image, viewGroup, false);
        StickerPreviewViewHolder vh = new StickerPreviewViewHolder(itemView);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = vh.stickerPreviewView.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.height = cellSize;
        layoutParams.width = cellSize;
        vh.stickerPreviewView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        vh.stickerPreviewView.setPadding(cellPadding, cellPadding, cellPadding, cellPadding);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StickerPreviewViewHolder stickerPreviewViewHolder, final int i) {
        stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView.setImageResource(errorResource);
        String packageName = stickerPack.identifier;
        String stickerName = stickerPack.getStickers().get(i).imageFileName;
        stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView.setImageURI(StickerPackLoader.getStickerAssetUri(packageName, stickerName));
        mContext = stickerPreviewViewHolder.stickerPreviewView.getContext();

        stickerPreviewViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v ->{
            Intent stickerIntent = new Intent(mContext, StickerDetailsActivity.class);
            stickerIntent.putExtra("nameOfSticker", stickerName);
            stickerIntent.putExtra("nameOfPackage", packageName);
            mContext.startActivity(stickerIntent);
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int numberOfPreviewImagesInPack;
        numberOfPreviewImagesInPack = stickerPack.getStickers().size();
        if (cellLimit > 0) {
            return Math.min(numberOfPreviewImagesInPack, cellLimit);
        }
        return numberOfPreviewImagesInPack;
    }
}
```

Activity 2:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

    public class StickerDetailsActivity extends AddStickerPackActivity {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sticker_details);
            ImageView stickerView = findViewById(R.id.sticker_view);
            Intent stickerInt = getIntent();
            String nameOfSticker = stickerInt.getStringExtra("nameOfSticker");
            String nameOfPackage = stickerInt.getStringExtra("nameOfPackage");
            try {
                InputStream stream = getAssets().open(nameOfPackage + "/" + nameOfSticker);
                Bitmap stickerBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stickerView.setImageBitmap(stickerBitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```